# Turn Array objects into JSON using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have dynamic data coming into my website like this:

```
[{
  "itemOne": { 
     "url": "www",
     "name": "Bob" 
  },
  "itemTwo": {
     "url": "www",
     "name": "fred"
  }
}]
```

Using jQuery or Javascript, I would like to turn this data into JSON, so it would be structured like this:

```
"products": {
    "itemOne": {
       "url": pageUrl,
       "name": productName
    },
    "itemTwo": {
       "url": pageUrl,
       "name": productName,
    }
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: the data coming in is JSON....

Comment: Yes, it's possible, for starters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: So assign it? Assume the JSON is called `data`. `var obj = {}; obj.products = data[0];` Voila.

Comment: What have you tried and what errors are you encountering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can just take the first object from the array and set it as the value of the `product` property of a new object. If you need to turn this object in to JSON, call `JSON.stringify` on the result. Try this:

```js
var arr = [{
  "itemOne": {
    "url": "www",
    "name": "Bob"
  },
  "itemTwo": {
    "url": "www",
    "name": "fred"
  }
}]

var obj = {
  products: arr[0]
}

var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: Pfft, copy cat :P

Comment: @SterlingArcher Wait, I totally had something for this...

Comment: Something something your own fingers? ;D

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is confused.  JSON is a text-based, human readable, security-neutral data interchange format.  Your first snippet *is* JSON.

If you want to turn that first snippet into an something that JavaScript can use, then...

```
var products = JSON.parse(data);
/* 'products' = an array of Objects */
```

If you want to turn 'products' back into JSON after you've done something with it, then...

```
var json_string = JSON.stringify(products, null, 4);
/* 'json_string' is now a 
   JSON-compatible text version 
   of 'products' with indentation 
   of 4-spaces */
```

See: [JSON @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) and [www.json.org](http://www.json.org/)